# Pivot table background color

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, pivot-table

I want to add a customized background color to my pivot tables using vba for values and headers. The header should be RGB = 102 0 133 and Values background should be 230 213 243.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference to a PivotTable by `worksheet.PivotTables([index])`. With this object, the data range is referenced by `.DataBodyRange` properties. By this, you should be able to change the color of the values and header (which is on top of the data) using `Range.Interior.Color`.

Comment: I tried and worked perfect. But it's not coloring the headers. Only the values below the headers. Any other way to do this?

Comment: As the header is always one row above the data, you can get the header range by using Range.Offset(-1) and range.resize()  to one row.